# Suspend updates to control from binding in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I am trying to find a way to suspend updates to `TextBox` control from binding when it has focus, and still be able to update source with `UpdateSource()` when user presses Enter key. Some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964930/1880407) suggest to suspend source from firing `PropertyChangedEvent`, but in my case, values are bound to multiple controls, and I don't want to suspend them from updating. 
Some other have also suggesed to remove binding from control, but that resets the value of `TextBox` (I want `Text` property to remain unchanged), and when I set binding again, it also first sends `FallbackValue` because setting the binding also clears value of property.

In `WinForms` I have accomplished this scenario by following code:

```
Public Class BindingTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

Private Sub BindingTextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Enter
    Me.DataBindings.Item("Text").ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never
End Sub
Private Sub BindingTextBox_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave
    Me.DataBindings.Item("Text").ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
End Sub
Private Sub BindingTextBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Enter
            Me.DataBindings.Item("Text").WriteValue()
        Case Keys.Escape
            Me.DataBindings.Item("Text").ReadValue()
    End Select
End Sub

End Class
```

How do I recreate this functionality in WPF?

**EDIT**:

Maybe that I was not clear. My goal is to have TwoWay binding, with Explicit updates to source, and to "pause" updates from source when control has focus.

Comment: You can try setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `Binding` to `UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit` and use `BindingExpression` to update manually using `UpdateSource()` method.

Comment: Updates to source are not the problem, I have done that. My problem is to stop updates FROM source, but be able to update it to source with `UpdateSource()`

Comment: Try setting Binding's `Mode` to `OneWayToSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I am not sure if it fulfilles demand. If Focus occurs it will update your Property from Text you put in textbox.

```
<TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Zmienna, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Zmienna, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: No, that is not my goal. My goal is to apply bind to source only when user presses Enter, and to suspend updates TO `TextBox` FROM source.

Comment: In order to stop updates from textbox from source you can use Mode=OneTime (retrieves data only when app starts). Then if enter is pressed update in code.

Comment: I want to retrieve updates all the time (the data changes about once per second), only to "pause" it when `TextBox` has the focus.

Comment: First you told you want to suspend updates now you want to retrieve all the time, make up your mind.

Comment: I want control to be updated all the time, but updates should be paused when control has focus.

Comment: TNX for update, but it does not complete fulfill my requirements, since when I enter `TextBox`, it throws binding error because of default value of binding (null string). Also, when I reenter same `TextBox`, it has value that was previously entered (bound to `Binding` object)